# How to convert time value into double/int value?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Is there a way to convert time value into double or int? Here's is the code to my timer which I wanted to change into double value because I wanted it to hold the time value as a double so later on I want to calculate the total price based on the data from the timer.I've tried the convert method but its seems to failed and I try to search other solution but mostly it was python language solution.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:latestfyp/QR/qrexit.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import '../QR/qrenter.dart';

class CountdownPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountdownPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CountdownPage> createState() => _CountdownPageState();
}

class _CountdownPageState extends State<CountdownPage> {
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  dynamic data;
  dynamic data1;
  double test = 0.000083333;
  var total;
  static const countdownDuration = Duration(seconds: 0);
  Duration duration = Duration();
  Timer? timer;
  bool isCountdown = true;
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
    reset();
  }
  // @override
  // void reassemble() {
  //   super.reassemble();
  //   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  //     controller!.pauseCamera();
  //   }
  //   controller!.resumeCamera();
  // }
  void reset(){
    if (isCountdown){
    setState(() => duration = countdownDuration);
  }
    else{
      setState(() => duration = Duration());
    }
    }
  void addTime(){
    final addSeconds = isCountdown? 1  : 1;
    setState(() {
      final seconds = duration.inSeconds + addSeconds;
      if(seconds <0) {
        timer?.cancel();
      }
      else{
        duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
      }
    });

  }
  void startTimer(){
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1),(_) => addTime());

  }
  void stopParking(BuildContext context)   {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QR()));
  }

  Future<void> _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    // Navigator.push returns a Future that completes after calling
    // Navigator.pop on the Selection Screen.
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      // Create the SelectionScreen in the next step.
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const QR()),
    );
  }

  void stopTimer({bool resets = true}){
    // data = duration *60;
    if (resets){
      reset();
    }

    setState(() => timer?.cancel());

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: Center(child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        buildTime(),
        // const SizedBox(height: 70),
        buildButtons(),
        // TextButton(
        //   child: Text('Scan to End Parking Time'),
        //   onPressed: (){
        //     Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QR()));
        //   },
        // ),

      ],
    )),
  );

  Widget buildButtons(){

    final isRunning = timer == null? false : timer!.isActive;
    // final isCompleted = duration.inSeconds == 0;

    return isRunning
        ?Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Start timer'),
          onPressed:(){startTimer();},
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Stop'),
          onPressed:(){
            if(isRunning){
              stopTimer(resets: false,);
            }

          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: stopTimer,
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Scan to end parking'),
          // onPressed: () => QR(),
          onPressed: (){
            data = timer;
            data1 = duration * 60 * 60;
            total = data1.toString() ;
            Navigator.push(this.context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QRExit(price: total.toString(), duration:data.toString())));
          },
        ),
      ],
    )
        :TextButton(
        child: Text('Start Timer'),
        onPressed:(){
          startTimer();
        }
    );

  }



  Widget buildTime() {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2,'0');
    // final hours = twoDigits(duration.inHours);
    // final minutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final seconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // buildTimeCard(time: hours , header: 'Hours'),
        // const SizedBox(width: 8),
        // buildTimeCard(time: minutes , header: 'Minutes'),
        const SizedBox(width: 8),
        buildTimeCard(time: seconds , header: 'Seconds'),
      ],
    );
  }
  Widget qr(){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: _buildQrView(this.context)),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                          width: 55,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: ()  async{
                              await controller?.resumeCamera();

                            },
                            child: Text('Scan', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext ctx) {
    // For this example we check how width or tall the device is and change the scanArea and overlay accordingly.
    var scanArea = (MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.width < 400 ||
        MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.height < 400)
        ? 150.0
        : 300.0;
    // To ensure the Scanner view is properly sizes after rotation
    // we need to listen for Flutter SizeChanged notification and update controller
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
      overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
          borderColor: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderLength: 30,
          borderWidth: 10,
          cutOutSize: scanArea),
      onPermissionSet: (ctrl, p) => _onPermissionSet(ctx, ctrl, p),

    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        // data = result;
        if(result != null){
          // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Test());
          Navigator.push(
              this.context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CountdownPage()));

        }
      });
    });
  }

  void _onPermissionSet(BuildContext context, QRViewController ctrl, bool p) {
    log('${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}_onPermissionSet $p');
    if (!p) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('no Permission')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  Widget buildTimeCard({required String time, required String header}) =>
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            child:
            Text(
              time,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 60,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(header)
        ],
      );
}
```

Comment: by time, do you mean the Duration() object? is so, you can use this function to get your duration based on seconds :

    countdownDuration.inSeconds
there are other metrics available, but consider that each of them will return the whole time in that metric, meaning that if you're going to calculate your duration to something like "2 minutes and 30 seconds", you need to divide the "inMinutes" on 60 and the remainder would be the number for seconds.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  You seem to be aware of `Duration.inSeconds` already, so are you asking how to convert a `DateTime` object to an integer? (You don't seem to use `DateTime` in any meaningful way in the code you've shown.) If so, there's [`DateTime.millisecondSinceEpoch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html).  However, without understanding *why* you need an integer, it's unclear if `millisecondsSinceEpoch` has the units and reference point that you want.

Comment: Sorry, what im trying to say is, let say the total hour is 1 hour 39 minutes. I want to change that value into double so basically into hours (1.39). Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
countdownDuration.inSeconds
```

which will return the whole Duration in seconds, also there are other units available like minutes, microseconds, and hours.

Update:  You can calculate your duration in hours like this:

```
countdownDuration.inMinutes/60
```

Comment: Sorry, what im trying to say is, let say the total hour is 1 hour 39 minutes. I want to change that value into double so basically into hours (1.39). Is there a way?

Comment: 1 hour and 39 minutes is 1.69 hours, so you can just divide the duration in minutes on 60.
but if what you really need is to convert 1 hour and 39 minutes to 1.39, this is the formula:
duration.inHours + (duration.inMinutes.remainder(60))/100

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understand:

```
    // convert hours & min into double
  String getTime(int hours, int minutes) {
    String hour = hours.toString();
    String minute = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) {
      hour = '0$hours';
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minute = '0$minutes';
    }
    return '$hour.$minute';
  }
```

You can change this according to your need and convert a string into double/int.

Comment: hey kashif thanks for the answer im just wondering where should I put this function?

Comment: call it where you are getting datetime (hours & min). pass argument into this function and it will return you a string, then convert it into double/int

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode a duration of 1h39m to a floating-point value of 1.39, you're just taking the number of leftover minutes, dividing it by 100, and adding the number of hours:

```dart
double encodeDurationToDouble(Duration duration) {
  var hours = duration.inHours;
  var minutes = duration.inMinutes % 60;

  return hours + minutes / 100;
}

void main() {
  var durations = [
    const Duration(hours: 0, minutes: 59),
    const Duration(hours: 3, minutes: 7),
    const Duration(hours: 25, minutes: 12),
  ];

  // Prints:
  // 0.59
  // 3.07
  // 25.12
  for (var d in durations) {
    print(encodeDurationToDouble(d));
  }
}
```

Although be aware of [fundamental inaccuracies when using floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/).

You alternatively could encode 1h39m as an integer 139 by multiplying the number of hours by 100 and then adding the leftover minutes:

```dart
int encodeDurationToInt(Duration duration) {
  var hours = duration.inHours;
  var minutes = duration.inMinutes % 60;
  return hours * 100 + minutes;
}
```

Or you could just use `duration.inMinutes` to obtain the total number of minutes instead of encoding it in uncommon ways.  You still haven't explained *why* you want duration encoded in such a way, so it's unclear why you can't just use that.